# SQL Server trim() Question

Tags: sql-server

I have a varchar field in the database. I want to do a SQL to get the values in the field, and do like a substring on the result. I want to only return the words between some beginning and ending. For instance, for the field value "We few, we happy few.", I want to return only "we happy".
Does SQL Server have a function to do this?

Comment: Generally if you want to extract parts of a string value like that, you may have a design problem in your database. You should not store comma delimited lists in one field, they should be individual records in a related table. Comma delimted strings can cause horrible performance problems unless you only ever want to return the entire string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be what you are looking for: [SubString msdn article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187748.aspx).

Answer (score 2):

Your question is a little unclear.  Substring will work for this specific case.  Check out [this msdn article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181984.aspx) for a list of all of the string functions.  From what I can tell you will probably need to use a few in unison.

Answer (score 0):

I find the page [String Functions (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181984.aspx) quite useful when dealing with strings in TransactSQL

Answer (score 0):

Hope this will answer your question...

```
declare @a as varchar(500) 
set @a='We few, we happy few.'
print Substring(@a,charindex('we',@a),2) + ' ' + Substring(@a,charindex('happy',@a),5)
```